# UIPickerView and empty core data array

Tags: ios, core-data, uipickerview

I have a viewcontroller showing items from a core data entity.  I also have a tableview listing records from the same entity.  The table is editable, and the user could remove all the records.  When this happens, the view controller holding the pickerview bombs because it's looking for records in an empty array.  How to prevent this? I'm assuming I need to do something different at objectAtIndex:row...

```
# pragma mark PickerView Section

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;  // returns the number of columns to display.
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [profiles count];  // returns the number of rows
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    // Display the profiles we've fetched on the picker
    Profiles *prof = [profiles objectAtIndex:row];
    return prof.profilename;

}

//If the user chooses from the pickerview

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    selectedProfile = [[profiles objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"profilename"];
}
```

EDIT******

Ok, I found what was causing the problem...on the PickerView I was setting a default..

```
self.profiles = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

selectedProfile = [[profiles objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"profilename"];

[pickerView reloadAllComponents];
```

When I take that out, it works like a champ.

Comment: When you delete object you delete objects in coredata managedObjectContext and commit the changes ? meaning you call save method ? .. if you do so refresh the and fetch data from context to array again...

Comment: How are you updating your `profiles` array? Please show that code and remove the rest.